# Vim: How to keep folds on save?

Tags: vim

In my current vim setup I have `set foldmethod=syntax` , however whenever I save my file it refolds anything I had opened. Any ideas?

FWIW this is my current [vimrc](https://github.com/MaerF0x0/VimSetup/blob/2c63af1c4c7aad22c0ecac5e653c474a1fb81d36/vimrc)

Comment: Your .vimrc mentions vim-go. Does this happen with anything else than go files?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This behavior is normal. Vim's default is not to remember which code you had folded vs. unfolded from one session to the next. You can save your current folds; when you finish editing a file, before exiting vim, enter the command `:mkview`. When you next open the file, if you enter `:loadview`, it will restore your folds. If you want this to happen automatically, add this code to your vimrc

```
augroup remember_folds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
augroup END
```

If you want more features, this plugin does the same thing http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4021.

**Update:** sorry, my original code didn't work. It should work now.

Comment: it's better to use silent load to avoid the error:
`autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent! loadview`

Comment: This is not a good solution, as the view includes mappings. Consider the following situation: you have a plugin `p`, you open `f`, close it, and uninstall `p`. Now, you open `f`: all your mappings relative to `p` are still there, although none of them will work, and might even create really weird behaviour.

Comment: That's not answering the question at all. He is not asking how to keep folds after exiting vim, he is asking for how to keep unfolds on file save. When the foldmethod=syntax vim folding again all the functions on each save.

Comment: This has the side effect that e.g. modelines won't be recognized when you add them later on. [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19333/20427) provides a solution.

Comment: @Rightleg this can be rectified by putting `set viewoptions-=options` in your vim rc, this makes it so `:mkview` ignores local bindings when folds are created.

Comment: Is it possible to disable loadview when `:e`? I only want to keep folds when I exit the buffer, not when I reload.

Answer (score 9):

I am not a vim config ninja, but I hacked various solutions to achieve this, which works for me on nvim/Neo Vim without throwing errors.

```
augroup remember_folds
  autocmd!
  au BufWinLeave ?* mkview 1
  au BufWinEnter ?* silent! loadview 1
augroup END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer is different than anwser from @lwassink ?

Comment: To answer @71GA: `?*` ensures that the filename is nonempty. This avoids causing problems in pseudo windows (I don't know the exact terminology for this) opened by other plugins, such as Telescope.nvim.

Answer (score 5):

Saving a file should definitely not cause Vim to reset folding. However, some autocmd on e.g. BufWritePost actions might trigger such behavior.

More specifically `vim-go` has an open [bug](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/502) which causes this issue with golang files. The bug's comments lists a couple of workarounds. Setting `g:go_fmt_experimental = 1` works for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
augroup remember_folds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent! loadview
augroup END
```

if you're having issues getting the folding to work with something like **Telescope** or other plugins that create buffers (windows, dialogs, etc), the above seems to work for me so far.

It basically requires a period in the name of the buffer (foo.sh, script.py, server.js, etc) to trigger. The dynamic buffers from things like Telescope don't seem to match that pattern.

Comment: Had problems with fzf, and that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those who use NeoVim:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufWinLeave"}, {
  pattern = {"*.*"},
  desc = "save view (folds), when closing file",
  command = "mkview",
})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufWinEnter"}, {
  pattern = {"*.*"},
  desc = "load view (folds), when opening file",
  command = "silent! loadview"
})
```

First 5 lines are saying: When  closing buffer (file or other buffers), do:
if buffer name follows pattern "*.*", save view (all folds). Another 5 is doing the same job, but backwards: load view (all folds) when opening the file.

When you open file for the first time, you may get an error, because you have no views saved. To prevent this from happening, I inserted `silent!` in loading view autocmd

Comment: It worked with Nvchad Neovim Config, thanks 